# Take advantage of the conditional get for script added via tags into an html page

Tags: javascript, html, http, frontend

is there any way to take advantage of the HTTP conditional requests when a script is added to the head section of a page?
What i would like to achieve is to cache javascript file dynamically downloaded and added into head section by script tags.
If it's not possible would be a good solution the usage of FileSystem APIs to cache locally the files?

Answer (score 0):

Normal caching rules apply to scripts. They are specified using the normal HTTP headers.

Adding the script element dynamically doesn't affect this.

Comment: thanks for the answer. But how i can make sure the browser set "If-None-Match" header to get the scripts?